# Openpyxl Hide Series Data Points from Legend

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a chart I've created using openpyxl. Everything turns out as expected, however I would like to hide the data points from the legend while keeping their formats in the chart. In short, I would like to hide/remove all of the data points from the right hand side of the chart while preserving the colors of the bars.[image]

Here's a snippet of code used to build the chart:

```
chart1 = BarChart()
series = chart1.series[0]

ndcs = Set()
scfs = Set()

for i, row in enumerate(results):
    if 'DNDC' in row[0]: ndcs.add(i-1)
    if 'DSCF' in row[0]: scfs.add(i-1)


for index in ndcs:
    fill =  PatternFillProperties(prst="pct5")
    fill.background = ColorChoice(prstClr="red")

    pt = DataPoint(idx=index)
    pt.graphicalProperties.pattFill = fill
    series.dPt.append(pt)

for index in scfs:
    fill =  PatternFillProperties(prst="pct5")
    fill.background = ColorChoice(prstClr="blue")

    pt = DataPoint(idx=index)
    pt.graphicalProperties.pattFill = fill
    series.dPt.append(pt)
```

FWIW, I tried to follow the example from the docs [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/charts/pattern.html), however I couldn't find anything specific about hiding the information on the legend.

My question is, what members/attributes will I need to toggle off to hide the data points from showing on my legend while preserving the colors of the bars?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have to dive into the source code, the documentation is seriously lacking.

Try:

```
chart1.legend = None
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `chart.legend.delete = True`

Answer (score -1):

nope is the previous one

chartcol_geologicaprog.legend = None